# slow avcodec_decode_video2, ffmpeg on android

Tags: android, performance, ffmpeg, decode

I am developing a player on android using ffmpeg. However, I found out that avcodec_decode_video2 very slow. Sometimes, it takes about 0.1, even 0.2 second to decode a frame from a video with 1920 × 1080 resolution.

How can I improve the speed of avcodec_decode_video2() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your device has necessary hardware+firmware capabilities, you could use [ffmpeg with libstagefright support](http://www.origenboard.org/wiki/index.php/FFmpeg_on_Android).

**Update**: here is the easy procedure to decide whether it is worth while to switch to libstagefright on your device for a given class of videos: use ffmpeg on your PC to convert the representative video stream into mp4:

```
ffmpeg -i your_video -an -vcodec copy test.mp4
```

and try to open the resulting file with the stock video player on your device. If the video does play with reasonable quality, you can use libstagefright with ffmpeg to improve your player app. If you see "Cannot Play Video", your device hw+fw does not support the video.

[image: "Cannot Play Video" popup]

Comment: I am using Samsung S3, can I use ffmpeg with libstagefright? Do you have a working example of using libstagefright?

Comment: There is an easy way to test whether libstagefright is worth while, se e the updated answer.

Comment: ffmpeg dropped libstagefright recently: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35563448/895245

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩: luckily, the software codecs are much faster than 2 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds about rite. HD video takes a lot of CPU. Some codecs may support multithread decode if you device has multiple cores. But the will consume massive amounts a battery, and heat the device. This is why most mobile devices use specialized hardware decoders instead of CPU. In Android using the MediaCodec API instead of libavcodec should invoke the hardware decoder.